# ValueError: Dependency on app with no migrations: account

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to deploy my code in heroku.
While deploying i complete all the steps
but i get error while migrate

i try these command

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations account
```

While running above command  i get

```
account/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model User
```

but while trying to migrate

I try

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate account
```

i get error

```
 raise ValueError("Dependency on app with no migrations: %s" % key[0])
ValueError: Dependency on app with no migrations: account
```

i also try

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

At this time also i get same error

the project is running successfully in localhost
with out any error

I am new to heroku please anyone can help with full instruction

Answer (score 2):

First try to run command **`heroku run python manage.py showmigrations`** to see what migrations have been done.
If it returns an empty list, you have to run **`heroku run python manage.py migrate`** to migrate the existing migrations.

After that, you can follow the normal procedures in tutorial

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: the steps you are mentioning is already done
as you can already see in question

Comment: When I do showmigrations, I see no migrations for my apps. However when I run the makemigrations command I do see the info that tables are created.

Answer (score 0):

my case

(heroku.com)
heroku dashboard
↓
app
↓
deploy
↓
Github
↓
Manual deploy

I was able to migrate